# sudo apt update not working on windows subsystem

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed ubuntu for windows subsystem for linux. I can run bash scripts and run basic commands like ls, etc.
Problem is I cannot run sudo apt update or sudo apt-get update. Cannot install packages ike ruby, pip. I get errors similar to below:

Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

[image]

[image]

How can these errors be resolved. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The error message suggests that you *See apt-secure(8) man page*. Did you try that?

Comment: @KenWhite, no. Not sure, how to do that.

Comment: `man apt-secure` from the command line. The 8 is a page number. Or you could try a search with Google for *man apt-secure(8)* or *man apt-secure*..

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks. It refers to unsigned repositories. I have used "sudo apt-get -o APT::GET::AllowUnauthenticated=true update" but same error. Is there a way to bypass the error.